# Manage session and cookie in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

Currently, my Rails 5.2 backend app is managing an API working with sessions only.

```
App::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

In the app, I only manage session[:user_id] to know when a user is logged or not.
Today, I need to enhance the client app (iOS) to store if a user if logged or not.
So, my first idea was to change the expiry date in:

```
App::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, expire_after: 1.day
```

This works but the cookie created to store the session_id is updated at each request... so the expiry date is undefined.

So I decided to add a new cookie when a user is logged:

```
cookies[:logged_in] = { value: 1, expires: 1.day }
```

This cookie is no updated at each request and keep the expiry date. It's what I want.

The problem is I don't know how to manage together the custom cookie and the session containing the user_id.
Even if I store the cookie and check its expiry date on the client app, the session_id containing the user_id will expire by default when the client app is closed/ or a browser is closed. And if I add "expire_after: 1.day" to the session, they won't have the same expiry date.

So my question is how to manage both session[:user_id] expiry date and cookie[:logged_in] expiry date together ? What did I miss ?

EDIT: more infos.
I want that the session[:user_id] stores the user_id as before in the database, but I want that the user is logged for 1 year for example... even if the session default cookie ends when the browser/client app is closed. I don't want that the cookie, even signed, stores the user_id if it's possible...
So the problem is what happen when the cookie[:logged_in] is not expired on the client, but the session containing the user_id has expired... How to manage that on the Rails side ?

Comment: Can you be more precise of the desired behavior you are trying to reach. It's not very clear yet.

Comment: Hi Maxence, I have edited my message with more infos.